# Set variable as property in a JSON request with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I need to make a json request with the url structure like : site.com/page?id=123

How do I pass the variable through the request and then return the results to the page?

```
    <input type='text' id='theInput'>
    <input onclick='getIt(); return false;'  />
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script>
        function getIt(){
        var x = ($j('#theInput').val() );
        $j.getJSON("http://site.com/page?id=", 
          {
        //how do i append x to request?
          },
        );
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is `http://site.com/page` your site or a third party site? If the latter you will run into same-origin-policy issues.

Comment: I am hoping to run two processes like this... one is same site, the other is a sub domain of the site.  Would I have to use JSONP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var id = $j('#theInput').val();
$j.getJSON('http://site.com/page', { id: id }, function(result) {
    // success
});
```

Also I would recommend you using unobtrusive javascript:

```
<input type="text" id="theInput" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me" />
<div id="results"></div>
```

And then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var id = $j('#theInput').val();
        $j.getJSON('http://site.com/page', { id: id }, function(result) {
            // manipulate the results
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also you should make sure that you respect the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) or your AJAX request might not work. Verify that `http://site.com/page` is the same domain as the one that hosts the page sending the AJAX request. If this is not the case you could configure your server to send a [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) response.

Comment: Thanks Darin!  Would I have to use JSONP if I am sending it to a subdomain?

Comment: Look at the table in the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) article. In which case are you?

Comment: Sweet this works!  I can see it in the get request.  Can you please explain to me a bit more how I manipulate the results to show in the #results div?